# is "go the way of disco" an idiom for "disappear"?

Tags: idioms

for example:

The real reason why you’re going to have a crummy retirement is that the conventional “defined benefit” pension plan of your parents’ generation, which provided a steady and reliable stream of income for as long as they lived, has gone the way of disco

Comment: It also suggests that it seemed glitzy and strong initially, but then faded away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's more an allusion to something that once was extremely popular but has withered and died to the point where very few genuine examples now exist. So yes, it means 'to disappear', but *gradually*.

Comment: I disagree on the "gradually" Disco is considered one of the shortest lived and most abrupt death in popular music. http://www.neatorama.com/2012/05/21/why-disco-died/

Comment: Some things that went away more gradually that you could describe something "going the way of" are typewriters, rotary phones, or leaded gasoline. For each of these, there was approximately a ten year period where they became more uncommon each year but were clearly still visible and certainly not rare.